# how to disable the script os_check_type.py when using different OS versions in the ambari cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, rhel, ambari, hdp

main issue - using different OS version in ambari/HDP cluster  ( as RHEL 7.0 and RHEL 7.2/7.5 )

After reading some posts as

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-register-host-with-different-OS-to-Ambari/m-p/151089

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/HDP-Support-for-mix-of-OS-Releases-within-a-cluster/m-p/97315

that discussed about using different OS RHEL version in the cluster

I see the solution about to disable the script:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
```

but not clearly how to disable it?

for example one option from my understanding is to remove the execution from the script as

```
chmod -x  /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
```

but not sure if this is the meaning !

```
more os_check_type.py
#!/usr/bin/ambari-python-wrap

'''
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
'''

import sys
from ambari_commons import OSCheck

def main(argv=None):
  # Same logic that was in "os_type_check.sh"
  if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage: <cluster_os>"
    raise Exception("Error in number of arguments. Usage: <cluster_os>")
    pass

  cluster_os = sys.argv[1]
  current_os = OSCheck.get_os_family() + OSCheck.get_os_major_version()

  # If agent/server have the same {"family","main_version"} - then ok.
  print "Cluster primary/cluster OS family is %s and local/current OS family is %s" % (
    cluster_os, current_os)
  if current_os == cluster_os:
    sys.exit(0)
  else:
    raise Exception("Local OS is not compatible with cluster primary OS family. Please perform manual bootstrap on this host.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: It's all RHEL 7, though, so what's the issue?

Comment: we have in the cluster datanodes machines with RHEL 7.2 and RHEL 7.6

Comment: I also share the post  that recommended to disable the  os_check_type.py  , in case of using diff OS versions

Comment: You're not using different versions. It's not RHEL 6 and 7, it's just 7. The minor version isn't critical here

Comment: so we can mix rhel versions as 7.0 / 7.2 / 7/5 / 7.8 ?

Comment: Yes. All the HDP YUM repos just list RHEL 7. Ambari will install and manage them all the same. Of course, there may be differences in external packages, but that's not something you can control without consistent OS versions. For example, in AWS, you would use the same AMI across all machines